# Program freezes and timer loop is endless

Tags: c#, winforms

My program binds "Z" key to a handler that activates a timer.
That timer triggers a mouse click.

Problem is that if I keep Z pressed more than 5 seconds, it gets stuck and on KeyUp it doesn't fire, variable doesn't change to `false` and loop is endless, **so it continues firing timer's callback when key is not pressed anymore**. Only way to stop it is via `ALT+F4`

My code is at http://pastebin.com/rbCgY1rb

I use globalKeyboardHook [from here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook)

Critical part of code is:

```
 private void keyDownCallback(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
                    if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "Z") {
                            timer1.Enabled = true;
                            this.forceNoLoop = false;
                    } else if(e.KeyCode.ToString() == "X") {
                            timer1.Enabled = false;
                            this.forceNoLoop = true;
                    }
            }

            private void keyUpCallback(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                    this.forceNoLoop = true;
            }

            private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                    if (forceNoLoop) return;
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, (uint)Cursor.Position.X, (uint)Cursor.Position.Y, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, (uint)Cursor.Position.X, (uint)Cursor.Position.Y, 0, 0);
                    lblClickStatus.Text = "clicked " + (this.clickTimes++) + " times";
            }
```

So question is: how to fix the freeze problem?

Comment: Please include the critical portion of the code in the question.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Why does it freeze? How to fix it?

Comment: @p.s.w.g and Doan, question edited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343440/keydown-freezes-timer-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: @SteveCav no, because that question has errors in the debugger. My debugger is empty with no errors

Comment: On a side note, why use a timer at all, why not just post the mouse click from key up?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try checking the state of the timer before enabling/disabling it?

```
private void keyDownCallback(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "Z") {
        if (!timer1.Enabled)
            timer1.Enabled = true;
    } else if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "X") {
        if (timer1.Enabled)
            timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```